# $ \forall n \in N$ edges of $K_{2n+1}$ can be partitioned to hamiltonian cycles.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A hamiltonian cycle is a cycle which  visits  each vertex of the graph  exactly once.
A hamiltonian path is a path which visits  each vertex of the graph exactly once.

We need to prove that:

1-$ \forall n \in N$ edges of $K_{2n+1}$ can be partitioned to hamiltonian cycles.

2-Then show that edges of a $K_{2n}$ can be partitioned to hamiltonian paths.

Note : We already know that every complete graph has a hamiltonian cycle. The problem here is that the question doesn't want just one cycle. I am not sure how to pove that such a partitioning exists.

Any help will be useful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonDecomposition.html

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you sir. I searched for the proof of this, but i could'nt find it.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X7690039X

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Now can you see how the second question (Hamilton paths) follows very easily from the first question?